# Need to extract a DataFrame to a JSON file under specific parameters

Tags: python, json, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame created from an Excel .xlsx file using pandas that looks like this:

```
    TypeName
    TypeA
    TypeB
    TypeC

    ElementName1
    1A
    1B
    1C

    ElementName2
    2A
    2B
    2C
```

To clarify, the first group of attributes describes the "name" of each type of attribute whilst the rest clarifies the actual values of each element. I need to extract this to a json file (preferrably using pandas DataFrame.to_json, but others are ok too) using the format:

```
    {"TypeName": {
            "ElementName1": {
                    "TypeA": "1A",
                    "TypeB": "1B",
                    "TypeC": "1C",
                    },
            "ElementName2": {
                    "TypeA": "2A",
                    "TypeB": "2B",
                    "TypeC": "2C",
                    },
            },
    }
```

After much toying with the parameters of the assets pandas offers however, I haven't been able to solve this issue as of yet.

Comment: pandas dataframes have i/o methods themselves. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html. Since you don't show any code or any type of desired output we can't give a more specific answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :-D Try to create a [minimal reproducible case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (with specific input, code that you have tried and expected output). That will help you getting more and better answers to your question. :-)

Comment: Apologies. After looking around the site and recontextualizing my contest I've both reformatted it and honestly changed the very basis of the question. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Ldac Much better now. No need to apologize. ^^

Comment: It does solve the issue - I ended up crafting a solution of my own however, since I found ordering the DataFrame with the first column of my Excel file as an index automatically ordered it like I wanted once Pandas did its to_json function.

Even still, yours also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to make the `TypeName` the first key in an elegant (non-manual) way, but this may help you anyway:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas


df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO("""
TypeName,ElementName1,ElementName2
TypeA,1A,2A
TypeB,1B,2B
TypeC,1C,2C"""))

df.set_index('TypeName').to_json()
```

That way at least you get this structure:

```
{
 "ElementName1": {
         "TypeA": "1A",
         "TypeB": "1B",
         "TypeC": "1C",
         },
 "ElementName2": {
         "TypeA": "2A",
         "TypeB": "2B",
         "TypeC": "2C",
         },
 }
```